# Make a UIView Canvas which can be used to draw lines with finger

Tags: ios, canvas, touch, draw

I am trying to write a UIView which works like a canvas that we can use a finger to draw on it. I implement a CanvasView, when a finger moves, it first draw the image which already exists and then it draw a tiny line which join the previous point and current point. It does draw image when I move finger, however, the image is fading away when I am drawing. And I do not understand why this situation appears. I know there are some other approaches to achieve a canvas with UIView, but I want to know why my implement is wrong. And below is my complete code. And I hope anyone to copy this code and run it, then my problem can be more intuitive.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CanvasView : UIView

@end

#import "CanvasView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface CanvasView()
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint startPoint;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint endPoint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage* oldImage;
@end

@implementation CanvasView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.startPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.endPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    self.oldImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.endPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    self.oldImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //draw image already exists
    [self.oldImage drawInRect:self.bounds];

    //draw new tiny line
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.startPoint.x, self.startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.endPoint.x, self.endPoint.y);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    self.startPoint = self.endPoint;
}

@end
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I am, too, interested in why the fading is happening.